# Number of primes between $2k$ and $(\sqrt{k}-1)^2$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to prove the following.

Let $\pi$ denote the prime counting function. Then for $k\geq 81$ we have
$$
\pi(2k)-\pi\left(\left\lfloor(\sqrt{k}-1)^2\right\rfloor\right)\geq 6.
$$

What I have done is just some experimental calculation which suggests that even if I write 19 on the right hand side of the inequality it will still hold because the difference seems to be slowly growing with $k$ (it is not that surprising as far as I know even if sometimes it decreases a bit). However, I have never attempted to solve similar exercises/problems before and do not know how to start proving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Prime Number Theorem
$$
\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}.
$$
Since $(\sqrt k-1)^2=k-2\,\sqrt k+1<k$ we have
$$
\pi(2\,k)-\pi((\sqrt k-1)^2)\ge\pi(2\,k)-\pi(k)\sim\frac{2\,k}{\log k+\log2}-\frac{k}{\log k}\sim\frac{k}{\log k}\quad\text{as }k\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Using this quickly solved my problem. I feel a bit ashamed of not even thinking about the applicability of the Prime Number Theorem... Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @SiXiM: you may also use the weaker (and more elementary) version, the Chebyshev bound: $$\log 2\leq\frac{\pi(k)\log k}{k}\leq\log 4.$$

Comment: Thank you! For $k\geq 17$ I have also managed too find the bounds
$$\dfrac{k}{\log k}\leq \pi(k) \leq 1.25506\dfrac{k}{\log k}$$.
Anyway, surfing through some webpages after your suggestions I see that there are a lot of different estimates and bounds and most of them can solve the problem - I have not tried to use all of them.